# How to prove that neural network estimates posterior distribution

Tags: probability, self-study, neural-networks, convergence

Let's say that I train a neural network in a classic binary classification setting where all the training data has labels in $\{-1, +1\}$. From my understanding, if I train the network with a log-loss function and softmax output layer, the network outputs will essentially estimate $P(y \mid \mathbf{x})$.

How do I prove this convergence mathematically? In other words, if $h(\mathbf{x};y)$ is the output of the network, how do I show that the minimizing the loss brings $h(\mathbf{x};y)$ closer to $P(y \mid \mathbf{x})$ over all $\mathbf{x}$ over time?

Thanks!

Comment: It sounds like you are looking for a mathematical proof that the log loss, as a function of the predicted probability, is minimized by the true probability. Is that correct? (This amounts to proving that the log loss is a [*proper scoring rule*](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/scoring-rules/info).) If so, this is a straightforward optimization exercise with a little calculus Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: @StephanKolassa Yes, I think that's exactly what I'm trying to do. Thanks for the insight, I'll give it an attempt myself based on what you said.

Comment: Notice that in order to converge to the true probabilities you need to assume that the network has the ability to approximate arbitrary functions (e.g. by relying on [universal approximation theorems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_approximation_theorem). A given network with a fixed number of neuron will not have this ability.